# Parallel processing in R - setting seed with mclapply() vs. pbmclapply()

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-seed, reproducible-research, mclapply

I'm parallelizing simulations in R (using `mclapply()` from the `parallel` package) and wanted to track my progress with each function call. So I instead decided to use `pbmclapply()` from the `pbmcapply` package in order to have a progress bar each time I run my simulations **(`pbmclapply()` is specifically created as a wrapper for `mclapply()`, so they should have the same functionality except for the progress bar)**.

I was able to set a seed and get reproducible results without a problem using `mclapply()`, but `pbmclapply()` is giving me different results with each run, which I'm perplexed by. I've included a pretty simple reprex below.

For example, this is using `mcapply()`:

```
## GIVES THE SAME RESULT EACH TIME IT IS RUN
library(parallel)
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(1)
x <- mclapply(1:100, function(i) {rnorm(1)}, mc.cores = 2)
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
z <- mean(y)
print(mean(z))
```

And this is the same code using `pbmclapply()`:

```
## GIVES DIFFERENT RESULTS EACH TIME IT IS RUN
library(pbmcapply)
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(1)
x <- pbmclapply(1:100, function(i) {rnorm(1)}, mc.cores = 2)
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
z <- mean(y)
print(mean(z))
```

The only difference between the two blocks of code above is the use of `pbmclapply()` in the second and `mclapply()` in the first, yet the first block gives me a consistent result every time I run it, and the second block gives different results each time it is run (though a seed is set in the same way).

**What is the difference in the seeding procedure between these two functions?** I would appreciate any feedback as to why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that in the utils.R file within the pbmcapply package it runs the following line:

```r
if (isTRUE(mc.set.seed))
      mc.set.stream()
```

If we compare this to what is being called when we run the `mclapply()` function in the parallel package we see that it runs:

```r
if (mc.set.seed) 
        mc.reset.stream()
```

This affects the results as reset stream will allow the code to be run from the globally set seed, whereas running set stream sets it to the a new random starting value using the initial seed. We can see this in the functions attached below:

```r
mc.reset.stream <- function () 
{
    if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") {
        if (!exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) 
            sample.int(1L)
        # HERE! sets the seed to the global seed variable we set
        assign("LEcuyer.seed", get(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, 
            inherits = FALSE), envir = RNGenv)
    }
}

mc.set.stream <- function () 
{
    if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") {
        assign(".Random.seed", get("LEcuyer.seed", envir = RNGenv), 
            envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
    else {
        if (exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) 
            rm(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)
    }
}
```

I believe this change may be due to an issue with mclapply when you want to call the mclapply function more than once after setting the seed it will use the same random numbers. (i.e. by resetting the r session you should get the same results in the same order with pbmclapply so first time I get 0.143 then 0.064 and then -0.015). This is usually the preferred behaviour so you can call the funciton multiple times. See [R doesn't reset the seed when "L'Ecuyer-CMRG" RNG is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070377/r-doesnt-reset-the-seed-when-lecuyer-cmrg-rng-is-used) for more information.

The differences between these two implementations can be tested with the following code if you change the line in the .customized_mcparallel funciton definition from mc.set.stream() to mc.reset.stream(). Here I have simplified the function calls in the package to strip out the progress bar and leave in only the calculation (removing error checks also) and the change in setting the random seed. (Additionally note these functions will no longer run on a Windows machine only Linux or MacOS).

```r
library(pbmcapply)
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(1)
pbmclapply <- function()  {

  pkg <- asNamespace('pbmcapply')
  .cleanup <- get('.cleanup', pkg)


  progressMonitor <- .customized_mcparallel({

    mclapply(1:100, function(i) {
            rnorm(1)
        }, mc.cores = 2, mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.set.seed = TRUE,
                       mc.cleanup = TRUE, mc.allow.recursive = TRUE)
  })

  # clean up processes on exit
  on.exit(.cleanup(progressMonitor$pid), add = T)

  # Retrieve the result
  results <- suppressWarnings(mccollect(progressMonitor$pid)[[as.character(progressMonitor$pid)]])

  return(results)
}

.customized_mcparallel <- function (expr, name, detached = FALSE){
  # loading hidden functions
  pkg <- asNamespace('parallel')
  mcfork <- get('mcfork', pkg)
  mc.advance.stream <- get('mc.advance.stream', pkg)
  mcexit <- get('mcexit', pkg)
  mcinteractive <- get('mcinteractive', pkg)
  sendMaster <- get('sendMaster', pkg)
  mc.set.stream <- get('mc.set.stream', pkg)
  mc.reset.stream <- get('mc.reset.stream', pkg)

  f <- mcfork(F)
  env <- parent.frame()
  mc.advance.stream()
  if (inherits(f, "masterProcess")) {

    mc.set.stream()
    # reset the group process id of the forked process
    mcinteractive(FALSE)

    sendMaster(try(eval(expr, env), silent = TRUE))
    mcexit(0L)
  }

  f
}

x <- pbmclapply()
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
z <- mean(y)
print(z)
```

For a complete remedy my best suggestion would be to either reimplement the functions in your own code (I copy pasted with some minor modifications to the functions from pbmcapply) or by forking the package and replacing the mc.set.seed in the utils.R file with mc.reset.seed. I can't think of a simpler solution at the moment, but hopefully this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Excellent answer. FYI: I plan on awarding you the bounty, but am intentionally leaving it open for the full term as that helps attract additional traffic to the question and answer, both of which are exemplary and deserving of extra upvotes from the community. Thanks for sharing your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Great question and excellent answer by Joel Kandiah!

Another solution would be to put your code into an R-Markdown-File. Knitting the file will always gives the same result. But showing progress is more complicated. You could also simply run your code from the command line via Rscript:

```
Rscript yourfile.R
```

This will also give the same result every time because you always start fresh. It will display the progress and you can also redirect the output into a file. For a long running simulations calling Rscript is also more robust than working with a GUI.

Not sure if this is adequate for your needs, but still wanted to share this as it works very well for me and does not require changing pbmclapply.